# ¿Cómo validar que ingrese numero positivo y pares al momento de ingresar los números en el llenado de la matriz?

Tags: c++

¿ Cómo puedo hacer para que me valide que solo ingrese
números positivos y pares en momento del llenado de la matriz ?

Este es el código que tengo  :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numeros[100][100],filas,columnas;
    
    cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: "; cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de columnas: "; cin>>columnas;
    
    //Rellenando la matriz  
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>numeros[i][j];
        }
    } 
    
    cout<<"\nMostrando matriz\n\n";
    
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar las 2 cosas que quieres, con una sentencia `if-else` es suficiente. Ambas comprobaciones quedan de la siguiente forma:

1. Para comprobar si el número que introduces es negativo: basta con el argumento del `if` `auxiliar < 0`.
2. Para comprobar si el número que introduces es par: basta con el argumento del `if` `(auxiliar%2) != 0`. Este operador `%` lo que hace es el módulo del número, es decir, realiza la división de `auxiliar` con (en este caso) el número 2, y devuelve el resto de la división. Por lo tanto, cualquier número par que se divida entre 2 siempre va a retornar 0, en caso de ser impar retornará el valor 1.

El código que buscas puede ser algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numeros[100][100],filas=0,columnas=0;
    int auxiliar=0;

    cout<<"Digite el numero de filas: "; cin>>filas;
    cout<<"Digite el numero de columnas: "; cin>>columnas;

    //Rellenando la matriz  
    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Digite un numero ["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cin>>auxiliar;
            if ((auxiliar < 0) || (auxiliar % 2 != 0))
            {
                cout<<"Digito incorrecto"<<endl;
                j--;
            }
            else
                numeros[i][j] = auxiliar;
        }
    } 

    cout<<"\nMostrando matriz\n\n";

    for(int i=0;i<filas;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++)
        {
            cout<<numeros[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTA:**
Date cuenta de la variable llamada `auxiliar`. En este ejemplo primero asigno la variable de entrada a `auxiliar`, y con ella realizo el `if` antes de asignarlo en tu array, ¿para qué? pues para que en caso de que el dato introducido no sea válido puedas rectificar y no guardarlo en el array, además de decrementar el valor de la variable de recorrido del bucle `j` para que siempre se quede a la espera de un dato de entrada válido.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: gracias me ayudaste mucho 

Comment: Acepta la respuesta si te ayudó ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fácil y sencillo, una vez obtenido el valor introducido por teclado usar un punto de control que tenga como condición:

- Que el número introducido por teclado sea mayor o igual a 0. Por ejemplo, (`a >= 0`).
- Para los números pares recuerda que el módulo de 2 es muy util, si el módulo de `n % 2` es igual a 0 significa que es **par**, si te da cualquier otro número que no sea 0 significa que es **impar**.

La implementación para ambos sería algo así:

```cpp
if (a >= 0 && a % 2 == 0) {
    matriz[x][y] = a;
}else cout << "valor imcorrecto, vuelva a ingresar..";
```

Reemplaza las variables por las variables de tu código e impleméntalo. Para un mejor uso puedes aplicar un bucle ***while***

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.